# How to call the public void start(Stage primaryStage) Method from a different class

Tags: javafx

I'am new to JavaFX, so my coding is not the best. My programme has one Stage with 2 different Scenes. For a better overview I have created a new class for the second Scene. From this second Scene I want to go back to first one, using  a button. The method: primaryStage.setScene(scene) is not working and I dont know why. Can someone please help me? :)

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane primarygridpane = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(primarygridpane,400,400);
            ...
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class Harnwegsinfektion {

    public static void create (Stage primaryStage){
        GridPane secondarygridpane = new GridPane();
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(secondarygridpane,400,400);

        buttonBack.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those 3 points (...) ? And what do you mean by "it's not working"? No error?

Comment: Those 3 points are standing for other code which is not important for functioning (mainly layout). I typed them in for a better overview. When I click on the button (buttonBack) the following errormessage pops up: "scene cannot be resolved to a variable". It seems like the button cant reference to the scene. For a better understanding a view description how it should work: In my main.class there is a scene (scene) in which I can chose an item from a combobox. Depending on the item I want to switch to the other scene (scene2). From there I want to go back to the first scene (scene). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `scene` variable is named `scene2` and you are calling `setScene()` with `scene`.

I don't really know when and where `create()` is called, but if you want to go back to the first scene from the button, you have to save the original one before switching :

```
public static void create (Stage primaryStage){
    GridPane secondarygridpane = new GridPane();
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(secondarygridpane,400,400);

    Scene originalScene=primaryStage.getScene(); //save the previous scene

        buttonBack.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primaryStage.setScene(originalScene); //go back to the previous scene
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much, you saved my day! :)
The function is called within the ... ;)

Comment: @Make_Ilanti Glad to have helped, make sure to check the answer to accept it :)